# Error in building MPI program

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm new to MPI. I'm trying to write a program for calculating PI using MPI and FORTRAN. But when I try to build the program I get the following messages.

```
make all
 gfortran -O2 -g \
    -o bin/MpiTest.exe \
    src/MpiTest.f -fno-range-check
C:/Program Files/MicrosoftMPI/Inc/mpif.h:344.38:
    Included at src/MpiTest.f:11:

       PARAMETER (MPI_AINT=z'4c00043b')                                 
                                      1
Error: PARAMETER attribute of 'mpi_aint' conflicts with PARAMETER attribute at (1)
C:/Program Files/MicrosoftMPI/Inc/mpif.h:359.35:
    Included at src/MpiTest.f:11:

       PARAMETER (MPI_ADDRESS_KIND=INT_PTR_KIND())                      
                                   1
Error: Function 'int_ptr_kind' in initialization expression at (1) must be an intrinsic function
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me here ?

P.S :

```
PROGRAM CalculatePI
        include "C:/Program Files/MicrosoftMPI/Inc/mpif.h"

            INTEGER :: i = 0, nThrows = 0, nSuccess = 0, ierror =0, numOfProcessors=0,myID=0
            REAL :: x = 0, y = 0, results = 0

            INTEGER :: Counter = 0

            call mpi_init(ierror)
            call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myID, ierror)
            call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numOfProcessors, ierror)
            ....
```

Comment: Could you show us the corresponding code?

Comment: 11th line is the include line. thanks.

Comment: If the `include` line is the 11th line the code you have posted is not the code you are trying to compile.  The code you have posted has `include` on the 2nd line.

Comment: prior lines are used for comments. I've put the 'corresponding' code snippet. thanks.

Comment: I would just install OpenMPI (compile it for gfortran) and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INT_PTR_KIND` is an Intel Fortran compiler extension function; that is, it is not a Fortran intrinsic.  The second of the error messages that you report indicates that `gfortran` is baulking at compiling code which contains references to a function it can't find.  I guess the first error arises from the same problem, you are trying to compile with the 'wrong' compiler.

As Alexander Vogt has suggested you might make better progress using a compiler wrapper such as `mpif90`, but it has to be the right wrapper, the one which calls gfortran and links with the MS MPI library.  Whether that wrapper exists I do not know, but look for it under `C:/Program Files/MicrosoftMPI/`.

However, since those errors emanate from the `mpif.h` file you have included you'll also have to find a corresponding include file for compiling with `gfortran`.  I don't use MS MPI but it won't surprise me if you find that it only provides tools, libraries and include files for compilation with Intel Fortran.

Answer (score 1):

You should not compile your MPI code with `gfortran` alone. Instead, use the wrapper provided by your MPI library. Typically it is called `mpif90`.

Thanks to High Performance Mark for the clarifications.

Comment: meh.  I think my answer's better, but then I would, wouldn't I.