# MS-MPI and MinGW Fortran

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran

[This](https://github.com/scisoft/autocmake/blob/master/test/fc_mpi/src/example.f90) is simple fortran90 program testing MPI.

I would like to compile it on MS Windows platform using MinGW64 Fortran and the known MS-MPI package.

However, it's not working due to missing "mpi.mod". When I replace the `use mpi` with `include 'mpif.h'`, it's giving other errors (below).

Any help, please ? Does the MS-MPI suite cooperate with the MinGW gfortran ?

PS1:
Working with MS-MPI and MinGW gfortran is not an easy task, https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/245dcda4-7699-494f-bbe1-b76eb19e53da/linking-msmpi-with-mingw-gfortran?forum=windowshpcmpi

---

```
C:\Users\milias\Documents\Dirac\software\autocmake-devel\ms-mpi>gfortran -fno- range-check   -c example.f90
mpif.h:344.38:
Included at example.f90:4:

   PARAMETER (MPI_AINT=z'4c00043b')
                                  1
 Error: PARAMETER attribute of 'mpi_aint' conflicts with PARAMETER attribute at  (1)

mpif.h:359.35:
Included at example.f90:4:

   PARAMETER (MPI_ADDRESS_KIND=INT_PTR_KIND())
                               1
Error: Function 'int_ptr_kind' in initialization expression at (1) must be an intrinsic function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in building MPI program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755272/error-in-building-mpi-program)

Comment: An exact duplicate. The solution is to use different MPI library, because Microsoft does not support gfortran. Or you have to manually correct these errors in the MS MPI headers. It is well described in the thread you linked, what more do you need?

Answer (score 0):

solved here, I apologize for the duplicate.

https://github.com/scisoft/autocmake/issues/85#issue-102874399